# How to save email attachment in Python or tell me there is no attachment?

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

This is the following code I am running... I am having trouble saving the attachment --

```
import win32com.client
import os

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
body_content = message.body
attachment = message.attachments

attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + attachment.FileName)

print (body_content)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BregmanM/PycharmProjects/test/TkinterApp/test13.py", line 13, in <module>
    attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + attachment.FileName)
  File "C:\Users\BregmanM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.SaveASFile
```

How can I go about fixing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attachment variable points to the Attachments collection (note plural vs singular). You need to loop through the items in the Attachments collection, and for each Attachment object call SaveAsFile.

Secondly, you are assuming that Items.GetLast points to the latest message. That is not true. Items collection is not sorted in any way until you actually call Items.Sort().

Comment: I know next to nothing about Python. Loop from 1 to Attachments.Count. Or use "for each" loop (don't know if Python supports that).

Comment: Got it to work man, thank you! `attachment = attachments.Item(1)`

Comment: Don't do that - firstly, you are assuming that there is an attachment. At the very least, check that Attachments.Count > 0. And what about other attachments besides the first one?

Comment: Well - that line just shows me how to extract 1, which means I am able to do it for many more is what I am trying to prove. In essence, this is really all I needed. But you are right. Thank you.